# Cross compile a library --- curlpp

Tags: linux, gcc, g++, cross-compiling

I have written a program using curlpp and run succesfully on intel machine.
And now I want to compile it using a arm compiler called arm-linux-g++
What I need to do is **recompile the library curlpp using the arm compiler**. But it is weird that the there are .a , .la file in output ,**but .so file is missing!**

Here is my step:

**1.recompile curl**

```
./configure --host=arm-linux --prefix=/root/curl/build/target/
make
make install
```

**2.recompile curlpp**

```
env CPPFLAGS="-I/root/curl/build/target/include" LDFLAGS="-
L/root/curl/build/target/lib" ./configure --host=arm-linux --prefix=/root/curlpp/build/target --build=i586
make
make install
```

**3. `move /root/curlpp/build/target/,root/curl/build/target/ to /root/usr/local/`**

**4. compile my program**
`arm-linux-g++ -I/root/usr/local/include -L/root/usr/local/lib abc.cpp -lcurlpp -o abc`

> And compiler complains that lcurlpp can't find (since .so file is
>   missing)

Please teach me how to compile in using cross-compiler.
Thank you very much.